# XDocument Error Nonwhitespace

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm getting an error when trying to build an XDocument. The error is happening inside System.XML.Linq.Xdocument under the code

```
 internal override void ValidateString(string s) {
        if (!IsWhitespace(s)) throw new ArgumentException(Res.GetString(Res.Argument_AddNonWhitespace)); 
    }
```

This code is generating a Null Reference Exception. Below is MY code for the XDocument, I'm lost as to where something I'm doing is causing this.

```
            XDocument folderviewContents = new XDocument(
                new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf8", "yes"),
                new XElement("LVNPImport",
                    new XAttribute("xmlns" + "xsd", XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")),
                    new XAttribute("xmlns" + "xsi", XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"))),
                new XElement("InterfaceIdentifier", "835"),
                //Start of FolderPaths 
                new XElement("FolderPaths",
                    new XElement("Folder",
                        new XAttribute("fromDate", "TEST"),
                        //attributes for Folder w/ lots of attributes
                        new XAttribute("toDate", "TEST"),
                        new XAttribute("contactName", "APerson"),
                        new XAttribute("email", "AnEmail"),
                        //value for that long Folder w/ lots of attributes
                        "Remittance Advice"),
                    //Facility
                    new XElement("Folder", "TEST"),
                    //PayorID
                    new XElement("Folder", "TEST"),
                    //RemitDate Year
                    new XElement("Folder","TEST"),
                    //RemitDate Month/Year
                    new XElement("Folder","TEST")),
                new XElement("DocumentType", "RA"),
                new XElement("DocumentDescription","TEST"),
                new XElement("TotalFiles", "1"));

             //Create a writer to write XML to the console.
        XmlTextWriter writer = null;
        writer = new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out);
        //Use indentation for readability.
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        writer.Indentation = 4;

        folderviewContents.WriteTo(writer);
        writer.WriteEndDocument();
        writer.Close();
        Console.ReadLine();
```

*Edit*
Updated code

Answer (score 1):

You were creating more than one element at root level. Assuming `LVNPImport` is your root node, just moving one closing bracket fixes this:

```
        XDocument folderviewContents = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf8", "yes"),
            new XElement("LVNPImport",
                new XAttribute("xmlns" + "xsd", XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")),
                new XAttribute("xmlns" + "xsi", XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")),
            new XElement("InterfaceIdentifier", "835"),
            //Start of FolderPaths 
            new XElement("FolderPaths",
                new XElement("Folder",
                    new XAttribute("fromDate", "TEST"),
            //attributes for Folder w/ lots of attributes
                    new XAttribute("toDate", "TEST"),
                    new XAttribute("contactName", "APerson"),
                    new XAttribute("email", "AnEmail"),
            //value for that long Folder w/ lots of attributes
                    "Remittance Advice"),
            //Facility
                new XElement("Folder", "TEST"),
            //PayorID
                new XElement("Folder", "TEST"),
            //RemitDate Year
                new XElement("Folder", "TEST"),
            //RemitDate Month/Year
                new XElement("Folder", "TEST")),
            new XElement("DocumentType", "RA"),
            new XElement("DocumentDescription", "TEST"),
            new XElement("TotalFiles", "1")));
```

I have tested this locally, and the `XDocument` is created without errors.

Comment: That solved that error, but now I'm getting another error when using XMLTextWriter and calling WriteEndDocument which says that I don't have a root level element.

Comment: Can you post that bit of code at the end of your question and I'll try to reproduce

Comment: Delete the line `writer.WriteEndDocument()`  - not needed as this is all in the `XDocument` you write into the stream.